# Does one Azure SQL database pricing tier have faster performance than an another for an individual query?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I want to confirm my understanding when comparing Azure SQL pricing tiers. Is it true that for a single query, it should run equally as fast on any service tier? But I might run out of DTUs (i.e. capacity) faster in one tier than another as I run more and more queries? Or is it the case that certain levels actually run an individual query faster?

I know there is a lot of info out there, but I'm just trying to get this answered more plainly if possible.

Comment: Just click the "Service Tiers" in the pricing page. It contains the detailed specs. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-service-tiers/ . Or consider, do you want in-memory tables or not? If yes, it's Premium only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `P` instances run makes them access data much faster than `S` instances. For many queries a `P` will run the same query, on the same data, faster than an `S`. Also available memory and CPUs gives `P` instances more options for faster execution (eg. parallelism).